# Not able to reach recovery or TWRP on Redmi 4A Only blank screen

Tags: twrp, fastboot, redmi

One week back I successfully unlocked,rooted,put TWRP and flashed LineageOS 17.1. Today morning i read [[GUIDE] How to Create Custom Splash Screen (… | Xiaomi Mi 5](https://forum.xda-developers.com/mi-5/how-to/guide-how-to-create-custom-splash-t3425054). After following the link now the device is not recognised by ADB,Fastboot on attachment with usb cable or no System boot. Stuck on black blank screen. Long pressing of power key or any other combination of keys give a flash of a static screen. Googled to get disapointment.

P.S. After opening of device and googling some more now device is visible in  Windows Device Manager as Qualcomm HS-USB Diagnostics 900E. It is still not visible to adb or fastboot by `adb devices` or `fastboot devices` which was responding to same commands previously.

Comment: Now I try EDL Mode but stuck with tools and lockdown.

Comment: you guys should help each other https://android.stackexchange.com/q/226838

Comment: 900E mode won't let you be even in EDL mode, rather thinking about fastboot. There have been different tricks used on different devices to get rid of 900E and enter in EDL mode. Most of the times completely discharging the battery does the trick and device enters into EDL mode when both volume buttons are pressed before connecting to PC. You can flash factory firmware in EDL mode. But completely discharged battery might not start charging again. So better is to open the device and disconnect battery from board for a minute or so. Some other devices might require shortening some points on board