# Redmi 8 bootloop

Tags: bootloader, rom, redmi

My Redmi 8 phone is in bootloop. It got stuck with its Remi logo and does not start.
I am trying to unlock the bootloader but I didn't find a way other than mi unlock which I don't know how to use it without knowing my mi account credentials.
Please help me...
Thanks in advance...

Comment: What were you doing before the phone got stuck in a bootloop? Did you do a system update/upgrade? Did the device reboot itself on its own or did you do reboot for some reason and observed bootloop? Do make an [edit] to answer all those questions. That said, if your device gets stuck in a bootloop, you shouldn't be going after bootloader unlocking. Factory reset the device. If that doesn't work, only then try to unlock the bootloader (would be harder for you in this situation). Do note that unlocking bootloader automatically factory resets the device!

Comment: i don't recommend factory reset without knowing mi account, unless you find method to by-pass FRP

Comment: this guide give you a base to start reading about EDL mode. i have heared about even EDL mode is asking for mi account authorization on new devices, but worth a try. once you 
have access in EDL mode you can flash firmware and erase FRP partition https://android.stackexchange.com/q/226838

Comment: search for **patched** firehose programmer or ask on [xda](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/anyone-known-a-firehose-patched-for-redmi-8.4234279) forum

Comment: just a broad collection (unfiltered) good luck [romprovider.com](https://romprovider.com/download-prog_emmc_firehose-qcom-phone-cpus), [firmware27.com](https://www.firmware27.com/2017/06/collectionprog-emmc-firehose-prog-ufs.html), [leakite.com](https://www.leakite.com/collection-qualcomm-emmc-programmer-files), [github.com](https://github.com/programmer-collection), [tuserhp.com](https://www.tuserhp.com/2018/02/prog-emmc-firehose-ufs-firehose.html), [firmwarego.com](https://firmwarego.com/index.php?a=downloads&b=folder&id=2288)

Comment: https://xiaomifirmwareupdater.com/archive/miui/olive