# Recover data, photo, & video from a dead water-damaged Android phone

Tags: data-recovery, screen, bootloader, water-damage

**Question
Recover data photo video from a dead water damaged android phone**

I have a old android mobile which was kept on table  on which glass of water falled and water entered the mobile as its battery was attached (unremovable battery) inside I couldn't remove it I desambled and unpluged the battery  wire and kept the open mobile for three days in sun and then connected and swtiched on it vibrates with no display.

I went to service center they without looking to it said to change motherboard and cost of motherboard is more then the new mobile then I went to local guyz they said whole mobiles display screen motherboard battery all will be changed and declared it dead damaged after 5-7 hours testing r&d

I had important data in it. I tried to find motherboard of mobile online or any old same model same company old model second hand mobile I founded a old second hand mobile working but following  before buying I have questions in mind

1. Can I recover the data from damaged mobile if yes how
2. If same mobile screen or board is available then can the data internal memory be fixed into another mobile
3. As the mobile is dead and vibrating can we boot into bootloader or through adb commands  can recover from pc connecting mobile. If yes how
4. How can we get the data from the damaged mobile any how any trick or experts advice
5. If display screen is changed of damaged mobile then is it possible to recover data
6. if motherboard of the damaged mobiles is changed and as the storage chip on main board then is it possible to recover data

Additional UPDATED

Just now after 6onths i again unscrewed dissambled the mobile is didn't saw after taking from local engineer now a bad news the battery is swollen and is useless to power charge them it's now working

As the mainboard/ display/battery if bought all new spares will cost is more than mobile cost and heavy I have option to buy another second hand old mobile of same model and try to replace or test my old water damaged mainboard with second hand working mobile phone and test if the data can came out becuase the engineer said display battery and board all have to be replaced ...

I again unscrewd dissambled the mobile is didn't. Heckled after taking from local engineer now a bad news the battery is swalen and is useless to power charge them

As the mainboard display battery if bought all new cost is more than mobile cost and heavy I have option to buy another second hand old mobile of same model and try to replace or test my old water damaged mainboard with second hand working mobile phone and test if the data can came out because the engineer said display battery and board all have to be replaced ...

**My question is if I replace swap  the new second hand same.model.mobiles mainboard with my old damaged mobile and if it works fine and if not then is there chance to shot the display or battery or other parts to (if my water damaged mainboard is shorted  damaged) then will it damage the display of new second hand mobiles mainboard to  while testing or will the other mobile work if done carefully**

Comment: you did right disconnecting battery and dry. userdata can be dumped from SP Flash Tool or QFIL but if it is encrypted dump is useless

Comment: @alecx bro it's model is Lyf wind 4s ls-5018 , will sp flash toll or qfil work if it's nit switch on it foving dispaly but vibrating...can data be recover if screen damaged....and what if mainboard damaged to

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/226838/recovering-data-from-mi-4c-able-to-get-only-to-fastboot

Comment: @alecxs brother I updated I checked the phone after posting and unscrewd and saw that battery is drasticlly swallen so no way to powe charge or switch on and no chances to use any other way the local enginner informed me that the mobile is short either display or the wires or battery or board he was not certain after testing r&d now the point is can I get and put the damged board to new second hand phoen and test if it works or will it damage shot  the new set to

Comment: EDL mode works without battery. from stock rom extract [prog_emmc_firehose_8909.mbn](https://repairmymobile.in/flash/lyf-ls-5018-stock-rom) this is the programmer required for QFIL

Answer (score 1):

assume you are running windows, I will give you short instructions how to read data off dead device in EDL mode with QFIL

disconnect battery from phone mainboard, press vol up + vol dn and connect usb-cable

you should see Qualcomm HS-USB QD-Loader 9008 in windows device manager Ports (COM & LPT) section

install Qualcomm HS-USB QD-Loader 9008 drivers

download stock rom and open QFIL

now follow the steps in this [tutorial](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=4100897), but instead <s>`devinfo`</s> you are interested in partition `userdata`

> - Select "Flat build"
> - Select your firehose (prog_emmc_firehose_8909.mbn)
> - Select tools, partition manager
> - Click ok
> - Right click userdata and click on "Manage Partition data"
> - Click on "Read Data"
> - Check the logs on the main window, it will show you where it will be saved (Most frequently in the Appdata/Roaming/Qualcomm folder)
> - Copy the file we read to somewhere like the desktop and make a backup in case it does not work.

now you got the raw dump of your `userdata` partition. you can mount it with DiskInternals Linux Reader and recover your files from `media` folder (as long as phone is not encrypted)

---

If your phone is encrypted you can swap mainboard with working device if eMMC flash storage chip is located on the mainboard itself

Comment: bro okay thanx will try all and let u know see if it works