# How to access Android phone's internal memory with broken screen?

Tags: internal-storage, data-recovery, xiaomi, broken-screen

I have a Xiaomi Mi Android phone. My screen is completely broken but there are some important data available in the internal memory of the phone.

Is there any way by which I can access and copy data from internal memory to my computer?

Comment: Hi Puneet, see https://www.androidauthority.com/extract-data-broken-android-phone-819324/ - if you can't enter the passcode to deencrypt (even with a USB mouse plugged in), it'll be very hard to recover the data

Comment: please don't recommend Dr. Fone which is totally scam

Comment: expert only: assuming you have [EDL](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/226838) access it might possible to modify splash.img and flash twrp.img on locked bootloader (at least for [Redmi 5a](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3772381))