# How to reliably recover data from a dead Samsung Galaxy S8 phone?

Tags: samsung, data-recovery, samsung-galaxy-s-8

My friend has a Samsung Galaxy S8 (not S8+) that has a broken screen, but after operating with this broken screen for a while, wouldn't boot past the Samsung logo, and now won't respond to a power connection at all.

So to be clear, the phone doesn't do anything when plugged in to power. No partial boot, nothing on the screen. Nothing happens.

**What are the options for recovering the data on the device, that's on the onboard memory module (not on the Micro SD card)?**

1. Is it possible to move the memory module to new phone hardware?
2. Could the phone still be partially alive and be able to use a diagnostic mode to download the data via cable?
3. What other troubleshooting steps should I use to diagnose what state the phone is in?

(I'm quite technical so feel free to get in to infinite detail.)

Comment: exynos or qualcomm? for qualcomm download [prog_ufs_firehose_8998_ddr.elf](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/s8-g950u-hardbrick.3668572/post-76266994) and dump from [edl.py](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/226838)

Answer (score 2):

According to [iFixit tear down](https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/Samsung+Galaxy+S8+Teardown/87136) Samsung Galaxy S8 has a separate flash chip, it is the chip marked orange:
[image]

But Samsung Galaxy S8 exists in multiple variants which can have a totally different hardware layout and components.

Technically a skilled person with the right tools may be able to desolder the flash chip and move it to a new mainboard or read it's content in a special flash chip reader.
But this whole procedure may be useless if the device was encrypted. I don't know if S8 comes encrypted by default. If it is encrypted all attempts to read it with a different hardware will (most likely) fail because the encryption key is not include in the flash memory.

Regarding the current state: If the phone does not power on only an expert on Samsung devices can answer that question.