# unlock password screen for htc m8 steps

Tags: adb, recovery-mode, bootloader, htc

I have an HTC M8 that is password screen locked.  I'm tryin to save the data on this phone. Can't get into settings cause its locked. Tried to install Twrp fastboot but can't I think because usb debugging isn't on. Try using Adb to run commands but doesn't work either. I want to unlock bootloader but I think this erase the data.
Any help is greatly appreciated, I'm stuck. Thanks

Comment: get HTC leaked prog_emmc_firehose_8974.mbn, dump partitions from [edl.py](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/226838), mount userdata.img on linux, delete locksetting.db and restore partition image